# What can I put in the *.latexmain file?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

My `*.latexmain` files are usually empty.  I just use the file name to indicate which file is the main file.

In the Vim Latex Suite files, I noticed a file `projecttemplate.vim` with the following content:

```
" Project name
" let g:projName = ''
"
" Project files
" let g:projFiles = '' 

" Vim settings/maps/abbrs specific for this project

" Modeline for this file
" vim:fdm=marker:ff=unix:noet:ts=4:sw=4:ft=vim
```

Then I notice in `texproject.vim` the following description:

```
" Tex_ProjectEdit: Edit project file " {{{
" Description: If project file exists (*.latexmain) open it in window created
"              with ':split', if no create ':new' window and read there
"              project template
...
" Tex_ProjectLoad: loads the .latexmain file {{{
" Description: If a *.latexmain file exists, then sources it
```

So, does it mean that I can actually put something in the `*.latexmain` file, like the project name, the project files, and even more advanced settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new to Vim-latex too. Maybe the answer you (actually **we**) are looking for are located [here](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project.html). In particular, in [9.1](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-project-settings.html) you can read that

*If a master file is found, then Latex-Suite :sources the file. Thus this file needs to contain valid Vim commands. This file is typically used to store project specific settings. Some typical per-project settings which are best put in the master file are [Tex_ProjectSourceFiles](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-latex-completion.html#Tex_ProjectSourceFiles)*

In the latter link it seems there are some useful options.